# Союз следствия "так что" перед причастным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация

Требуется ли запятая после "так что"?
*Так что(,) промучившись весь день, он принял решение.*

Answer (score 1):

Почему перед причастным оборотом? Ведь это деепричастный! Он обособляется с двух сторон.